# Get Screenshot Path in Android Phone Programatically

Tags: android, path, screenshot

New in Android. how to get the Screenshot path using code.need to load images from screenshot directory. found screenshot path is different in different devices based on Manufacturer and OS version. please help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For getting screenshot path, Android's API has no fixed path for screenshots but

```
File pix = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
File screenshots = new File(pix, "Screenshots");
```

For more info you can check [this.](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/screenshot/GlobalScreenshot.java#L97)

this might be work.